# How to send array javascript to php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send an array with ajax to PHP. Could someone please
suggest a way to achieve it ?

My Code :

```
 guardarRuta: function(){

            console.log('Guardando ruta...');

            for (var i = 0; i < marcadores.length; i++) {
                latLngMarcadores.push({'tipo': 'parada', 'latitud': marcadores[i].position.lat(), 'longitud': marcadores[i].position.lng()});
            }


            latLngOrigenDestino.push({'tipo': origenDestino[0].tipo, 'latitud': origenDestino[0].marker.position.lat(), 'longitud': origenDestino[0].marker.position.lng()});
            latLngOrigenDestino.push({'tipo': origenDestino[1].tipo, 'latitud': origenDestino[1].marker.position.lat(), 'longitud': origenDestino[1].marker.position.lng()});


            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://becea.mx/dabbawalas_valeria/adm/save_route_adm.php', 
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    nombre: 'RutaNueva',
                    data: {"marcas" : JSON.stringify(latLngMarcadores)},
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'status'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    //Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Listo', 'Ruta guardada con éxito!');
                },
                failure: function() {
                    //Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                    Ext.Msg.alert('ERROR', 'Error de servidor');
                }
            });
        }

<?php

$elements = json_decode($_POST['marcas']);
echo($elements[0]);


?>
```

Comment: <?php

$elements = json_decode($_POST['marcas']);
echo($elements[0]);


?>

Comment: you have not send with JSON.stringify(latLngMarcadores), send like  data: {"marcas" : latLngMarcadores}

Comment: and these way it will json or array in php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask refer this before posting your query

Answer (score 1):

First, as pointed by @Burak Öztürk, you must directly send data as is (not using `JSON.stringify()`), like this:

```
params: {
    nombre: 'RutaNueva',
    data: {"marcas" : latLngMarcadores},
},
```

Then data is an object of objects, not an array.

Currently in PHP you're decoding it with:

```
 $elements = json_decode($_POST['marcas']);
```

This keeps objects as objects! Instead use:

```
 $elements = json_decode($_POST['marcas'], TRUE);
```

This way, objects become associative arrays and you can access and iterate them as expected.

Comment: can i do this?? $value = $elements[0]);

Comment: @ValeriaTorres If you used the second form above, yes. In the other hand, as ponted by Burak Öztürk, you _must_ send data directly as `{"marcas": latLngMarcadores}` (don't use `JSON.stringify()`).

Comment: <?php

 require ('config.php');
 $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);

$elements = json_decode($_POST['marcas'], true);


$uno = $elements[0];

$resultado = array("elemento" => $uno);
echo json_encode($resultado);

?>    in console: responseText: "{"elemento":null}" i can't get the value :'(

Comment: @ValeriaTorres What do you get with `print_r($elements);`?